# Need of p-value adjustment when analyzing all possible pairs of factor levels in linear model

Tags: linear-model, bonferroni, contrasts, adjustment

I have a nominal (not ordinal) variable with $K$ levels (these are actualy some groups of patients) and I run linear model in which:

- this nominal variable is one of IV's (others are age, sex and so on),
- DV is quality of life (quantitative variable).

I'm interested in anwsering the question which groups differ from which in terms of quality of life controlling for other IV's (age, sex, ...).

To get comparisons for each possible pair of groups, I run $K-1$ models with different reference group in each.

The question is: should I apply some p-value correction to p-values obtained this way?

Comment: Please read the large literature on multiplicity testing.  But a better way to think about this is to use the perfect multiplicity adjustment; one that is also unique: the ANOVA-type overall $F$ or $\chi^2$ test with $K-1$ d.f.  After that I suggest getting simultaneous confidence intervals for all the candidate contrasts (see for example the R `rms` package `contrast.rms` function).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank, you. I'll try with this approach

Comment: Thanks for the "thanks" but upvoting is the preferred way to show thanks on this site.

Comment: I'll upvote when I'll try your solution and it proves useful. For now I'm a bit confused. I ran example form `?contrast.rms` (the one ending with `contrast(f, list(x2=c('a','a','b')), list(x2=c('b','c','c')), type='individual')`. And I repeated analysis with two `lm`'s as I described in my question. Results are perfectly the same.

Comment: Now I added `x1` as a DV in `f`. Now the two approches (`rms` and `lm`) differ. Now I have to find out, why.

Comment: Regarding your next-to-last comment the two should agree.  You see different (more appropriate) confidence intervals when you use the 'simultaneous' confidence type with `contrast`.

Comment: If you wait until you try something before upvoting, then also wait until you try it before adding "thanks" comments.